# ProcessResult.stdout has partial content

Tags: macos, shell, dart

I am executing the `brew outdated` command using:

```dart
Process.run('brew', 'outdated')
```

and read the output via:

```dart
procesResult.stdout.toString()
```

Instead of the expected output such as:

```
gnutls (3.7.8) < 3.7.8_1
graphviz (7.0.5) < 7.0.6
guile (3.0.8_3) < 3.0.8_4
```

I get the string:

```
gnutls
graphviz
guile
```

How can I get the package version data?

dart --version reports:

```
Dart SDK version: 3.0.0-76.0.dev (dev) (Fri Dec 30 09:07:04 2022 -0800) on "macos_arm64
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `-v` option with `brew outdated`.

Compare:

```
$ brew outdated | cat   
autoconf
automake
```

Versus:

```
$ brew outdated -v | cat
autoconf (2.69) < 2.71
automake (1.16.2) < 1.16.5
```

However, if you're planning to do any parsing of the output, you may want to consider the `--json` option:

```
$ brew outdated --json
{
  "formulae": [
    {
      "name": "autoconf",
      "installed_versions": [
        "2.69"
      ],
      "current_version": "2.71",
      "pinned": false,
      "pinned_version": null
    },
    {
      "name": "automake",
      "installed_versions": [
        "1.16.2"
      ],
      "current_version": "1.16.5",
      "pinned": false,
      "pinned_version": null
    },
...
```

Use `brew help outdated` for more information.

Comment: Thanks, that works but I am curious, in the shell brew outdated produces the output that includes versions, why do versions disappear when invoking from Dart (and when piping to cat) ? Some sort of interactive vs. non interactive logic?

Comment: @DavidSoroko Yes, I presume so. Personally I'm not a fan of changing the behavior in that way based on interactive vs. non-interactive.